# use login from other selenium session

Tags: selenium, authentication, cookies

I would like to stay logged in a site which require login every about 2 hours. My idea is to open a parallel session, login and inject the cookies in the first session.
To achieve this, firstly, i tried to create a small example to use the use the cookies of webdriver_chrome session 1 to webdriver_chrome session 2, but a new login is asked.

Thanks in advance for your help

```
import pickle
import os
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep

import os
import pickle

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")        
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

driver.get("https://BANK_WEB_SITE.com/login/")
sleep(5)

LOGIN()

pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")        
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.refresh()
sleep(5)

driver2.get("https://BANK_WEB_SITE.com/MY_PORTFOLIO")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I solved the issue as the following code. The solution was: 

1) fix the mistake changing "driver.add_cookie(cookie)" to "driver2.add_cookie(cookie)" 
2) load the web page before loading cookies



import pickle
import os
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep

import os
import pickle


option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")        
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)




driver.get("https://BANK_WEB_SITE.com/login/")
sleep(5)

LOGIN()




pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")        
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

driver2.get("https://BANK_WEB_SITE.com/MY_PORTFOLIO/")


cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))

for cookie in cookies:
    driver2.add_cookie(cookie)
driver2.get("https://BANK_WEB_SITE.com/MY_PORTFOLIO/")
```